# cron: Run .sh as root

Tags: linux, cron, archlinux

To make things clear first: I'm using a virtual machine which is offline - security is therefor no showstopper for my need.

I have a simple bash script which performs which uses wmctrl to gracefully closes a process. KILL is not an option:

```
* * * * * sudo wmctrl -xc notepadqq-bin.Notepadqq
* * * * * /bin/echo "works" >> /home/usr/cron.log
```

I tried `sudo crontab -e` as well as `crontab -e`, the cron.log is written every minute, however the wmctrl command is not working.

I even tried to `echo "password" | sudo -S rm somefile` but this doesnt work for me either.

TIA!

Comment: If security isn't much of an issue, can you [edit sudoers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt) to allow you to run the commands you need as root without the password prompt?

Comment: Check out the [cron tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) for how to deal with sudo, X11 and error logging

Comment: Why don't you run it in root's crontab?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar: Perhaps, but there are still a lot of cron questions here. One could argue that crontab uses a specialized language, and these questions are about how to program in it.

Comment: @KeithThompson One could argue that, but one would be wrong (IMHO). By that logic, questions about iptables and `/etc/passwd` would be appropriate here.

Comment: @KeithThompson And his question isn't even about the crontab config file language, it's just about how to run a shell command from cron and dealing with the permissions issues.

Comment: @Barmar: I see your point, but there are currently over 14,000 questions here with the "cron" tag. It might be an interesting issue to discuss on [meta].

Comment: @KeithThompson Much of that is historical, and I would probably vote to close many of them as off-topic. But just having the `cron` tag doesn't necessarily mean that the question is specifically about `cron`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

First I'm going to make some assumptions (please correct me if these are wrong and I'll try to adapt the answer for you)

## Assumptions:

- you want to use `cron` and not any old job manager (I think this is safe from your question)
- you are already familiar with `cron` and would like the `cronjobs` to actually run as often as possible (this seems odd to me but may not be central to the question at hand) ( Edit:
  I also agree with that other guy's recommendation to look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info as it provides more in depth discussion on the use of cron )
- you want to use `sudo` for root privileges and not have the `cron` daemon run as `root` (which is normal on most systems)
- you are not satisfied with `chown 0:0 $(which wmctrl)` the effect of `chmod 4755 $(which wmctrl)` or more restrictive `chmod 4755 $(which wmctrl)`
- the results of a cron tab line "* * * * * sudo wmctrl -d >> /home/usr/cron.log" shows this "notepadqq-bin.Notepadqq" is still active from cron's perspective (IF THIS IS NOT THE CASE check the environment variables for wmctrl are preserved from cron't perspective. and let me know this assumption was wrong)
- your comment "even tried to echo "password" | sudo -S rm somefile but this doesn't work for me either." implies you have a password for using sudo
- You mean your comment "security is therefor no showstopper for my need"

## Ensure Sudoers allows the script call

Given those assumptions, I'd recommend first looking into how sudo is setup:

#### Try this:

(DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WITHOUT THE `visudo` command you can corrupt your system)
`export EDITOR=vi ; sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers`

you will want a line similar to this:

`%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

OR

`cron ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

given that you can be sure the issue is not a password prompt issue with sudo and that the command (infact ALL commands run via `sudo`) are run as root by default (when not using `-u` to set to another user)

Hope this helps